# How to count strings in specified field within each line of one or more csv files

Tags: python-3.x, linux, parsing, typeerror, counting

Writing a Python program (ver. 3) to count strings in a specified field within each line of one or more csv files.

Where the csv file contains:

```
Field1, Field2, Field3, Field4
A, B, C, D
A, E, F, G
Z, E, C, D
Z, W, C, Q
```

the script is executed, for example:

```
$ ./script.py 1,2,3,4 file.csv
```

And the result is:

```
A       10
C       7
D       2
E       2
Z       2
B       1
Q       1
F       1
G       1
W       1
```

**ERROR**
the script is executed, for example:

```
$ ./script.py 1,2,3,4 file.csv file.csv file.csv
```

Where the error occurs:

```
for rowitem in reader:
    for pos in field:
        pos = rowitem[pos] ##<---LINE generating error--->##

        if pos not in fieldcnt:
            fieldcnt[pos] = 1

        else:
            fieldcnt[pos] += 1
```

**TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str**

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Judging from the output, I'd say that the fields in the csv file does not influence the count of the string. If the string uniqueness is case-insensitive please remember to use `yourstring.lower()` to return the string so that different case matches are actually counted as one. Also do keep in mind that if your text is large the number of unique strings you might find could be very large as well, so some sort of sorting must be in place to make sense of it! (Or else it might be a long list of random counts with a large portion of it being just 1s)

Now, to get a count of unique strings using the `collections` module is an easy way to go.

```
file = open('yourfile.txt', encoding="utf8")
a= file.read()

#if you have some words you'd like to exclude
stopwords = set(line.strip() for line in open('stopwords.txt')) 
stopwords = stopwords.union(set(['<media','omitted>','it\'s','two','said']))
# make an empty key-value dict to contain matched words and their counts
wordcount = {}
for word in a.lower().split(): #use the delimiter you want (a comma I think?)
    # replace punctuation so they arent counted as part of a word
    word = word.replace(".","")
    word = word.replace(",","")
    word = word.replace("\"","")
    word = word.replace("!","")
    if word not in stopwords:
        if word not in wordcount:
            wordcount[word] = 1
        else:
            wordcount[word] += 1
```

That should do it. The `wordcount` dict should contain the word and it's frequency. After that just sort it using `collections` and print it out.

```
word_counter = collections.Counter(wordcount)
for word, count in word_counter.most_common(20):
    print(word, ": ", count)
```

I hope this solves your problem. Lemme know if you face problems.